# Why did SN10 rest at a slight incline after landing?

Tags: spacex, landing

Recently when SpaceX's SN10 landed, before it exploded, it sat still on the ground for a few minutes.

It appears to be resting at a slight incline.

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: It landed hard. Seems like one of the landing feet got damaged.

Comment: Also, 3 of the 6 landing didn't lock into position - you can see them flapping up and down in the final descent after the flip.